# Swift UIDevice.currentDevice() not compiling

Tags: ios, swift, uidevice

I have a swift project in which i want to retrieve the name of the device and show in in a `UITableViewCell`.
But when i want to call `UIDevice.currentDevice()` in

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

the compiler fails with:

> Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc
>   failed with exit code 1
>
> The following build commands failed:
>       CompileSwift normal arm64 "path to project folder"/custom_tableview_controller.swift
>       CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
>   (2 failures)

The awkward thing is calling `UIDevice.currentDevice()` in any other file than my `custom_tableview_controller.swift` file is working.

Additional information:
- Xcode 6.4(6E35b)
- Debug

Comment: Please show the full line where you use `UIDevice.currentDevice()`

Comment: `dsl_textfield_cell!.dsc_textfield.text = UIDevice.currentDevice().name` is the full line, but it also won't compile when i just write `UIDevice.currentDevice()`in a new line without using it

Comment: Weird. Same Xcode version and it works for me. Suggestion: clean Xcode (clean build + clean derived data).

Comment: Calling the line in application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool is working though. Clean build + derived data did't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create that for get UIDevice in framework with Swift :

**Create Obj-c Header.h and add**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

/**
 *  Static Current Device
 *  @note Can't get UIDevice CurrentDevice in Swift, Hack with obj-c
 *
 *  @return UIDevice
 */
static UIDevice* Device() { return [UIDevice currentDevice]; }
```

**In your target Framework -> Build Phases make this :**

[image]

**In your target Framework.h add :**

```
#import <BSStaticObjc.h>
```

**Now in Swift call method**

```
Device()
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been driving me crazy as well. I can't fix it. As a workaround I made an Objective-C class that solely sublcasses UIDevice. My class is `AWDevice`. In Swift the compiler is happy with `AWDevice.currentDevice()`

This is really strange.

Comment: Great! I had the same issue. It took me quite some time to comment out almost half of my source code until it turned out the UIDevice was causing the compile issue. I was first searching for the compiler message on Stackoverflow for a solution but was not successful. So for others having the same issue, here is the compiler error for this bug:   `Global variable initializer type does not match global variable type!
%struct._class_t** @"OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_"
LLVM ERROR: Broken module found, compilation aborted!`   please note: you need to select **All Messages** to see this error