# Swift UIDevice build error

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I get the following build error when using the UIDevice class in swift.

`Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1`

`Global variable initializer type does not match global variable type!
%struct._class_t** @"OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_"
LLVM ERROR: Broken module found, compilation aborted!`

The code that triggers the error is simply `print(UIDevice.currentDevice())`

Am I doing something wrong, or does anyone know a workaround?

And yes i've imported UIKit  :)

*** Edit ***

Here is the function i'm using, note that commenting out the UIDevice reference fixes the build error

```
func setAFHTTPRequestOperationManager(manager : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager) {
    manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
    manager.requestSerializer = AFHTTPRequestSerializer()
    // This causes compile issue?
    uuid = (UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor?.UUIDString)!
    manager.requestSerializer.setValue(uuid, forKey: K.API.HeaderFields.DeviceToken)

    var types = NSSet()
    types = manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes
    types = types.setByAddingObject(K.API.HeaderFields.TextContentType)
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = types as Set<NSObject>
    manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 30
    manager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
    afNetworkingManager = manager
}
```

Comment: I tried it, I have no problem, so it should be something else than your print which cause the problem

Comment: I tried print(UIDevice.currentDevice()) and it is working fine and showing in log.

share your code or screen shot. may be other issue.

Comment: @AncAinu commenting out the print statement fixes any build issues. I'm wondering whether it's an import or settings issue judging by feedback.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312378/swift-uidevice-currentdevice-not-compiling

Comment: I get the same error for `NSThread.isMainThread()` Compiling with Xcode 7.2.

Answer (score 1):

Are you also using `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` somewhere?  If so, try using `UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom` instead.